# Adding class instead of inline styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

the following code I have written for inline styling, instead of that i need to provide the class from from different .css file using jquery .addClass method. How Can I do that?

```
$(keywords).each(function(){                 
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["i"]);              
        var rs = "<span style='background-color:#FF6666;font-weight:bold'>$1</span>";  
        if(el.length > 0){
            el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
        }

    });
```

Comment: You don't have to replace like that, before I suggest a solution, can you please show the HTML code where you are trying to do this? Or what exactly is `keywords`, `el` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(keywords).each(function(el){                 
     $(el).addClass('yourClass');
});
```

Comment: modify it to this `$(el).addClass('yourClass').attr("style", "");` and that'll clear the inline style after adding class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to style your newly created span element just replace `style="..."` with `class="className"`, no need to use addClass

```
$(keywords).each(function(){                 
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["i"]);              
        var rs = "<span class="class">$1</span>";  
        if(el.length > 0){
            el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
        }
    });
```

Or, if you have to set class to a different object, just do

```
$("selector").addClass("className")
```

Comment: thanks a lot , the      var rs = "<span class="class">$1</span>";  thing worked.

Comment: Further to this I m facing one more issue- by applying above changes i am able to highlight the first occurrence  keyword but not the subsequent once.

Comment: try to replace `new RegExp("("+this+")", ["i"]); ` with  new RegExp("("+this+")", "ig");` (g means global search, do not stop at first match)